# subquery returning more values

Tags: sql, subquery

```
select inf.item_name,Closing_Quantity as Opening ,
(
    select Closing_Quantity 
    from ProductionFinishedGoods12 pf 
    join invFinishedStock inf
    on inf.id=pf.Finished_Goods where pf.date='2019/08/02' 
) as Closing
from ProductionFinishedGoods12 pf 
join invFinishedStock inf
on inf.id=pf.Finished_Goods
where pf.date  < '2019/08/02'
```

In the above code i want to find the closing balance from subquery but returning me more than 1 rows in return.
Actually the subquery returns values of two different products how can solve this?

Comment: As you confirm it is returning results for 2 different products, you have couple of options like - take average, take MAX or Min, Take Any One comes first. Take decision based on requirement. Also if you can add some sample data with your expected output, that will help.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538284/subquery-returning-more-values) as it is not clear how to solve these tied records..

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You are not filtering by any product ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a correlated subquery.  However, I have to speculate on what you are really doing, because you have not provided sample data and desired results.

So I think:

```
select inf.item_name, pf.Closing_Quantity as Opening,
       (select pf.Closing_Quantity 
        from ProductionFinishedGoods12 pf2
        where pf2.Finished_Goods = inf.id and
              pf.date = '2019/08/02' 
       ) as Closing
from ProductionFinishedGoods12 pf join
     invFinishedStock inf
     on inf.id = pf.Finished_Goods
where pf.date < '2019/08/02'
```

Your dates don't look correct for Oracle, but I assume you know why you are using that format.

Answer (score 0):

If the subquery returns more than 1 rows you must make sure that the `Closing_Quantity` returned is about the selected `item_name`, so add a condition to its where clause:

```
select inf.item_name, Closing_Quantity as Opening ,
(
    select Closing_Quantity 
    from ProductionFinishedGoods12 p 
    join invFinishedStock i
    on i.id=p.Finished_Goods 
    where p.date='2019/08/02'
    and i.item_name = inf.item_name 
) as Closing
from ProductionFinishedGoods12 pf 
join invFinishedStock inf
on inf.id=pf.Finished_Goods
where pf.date  < '2019/08/02'
```